# How to disable network manager service permanently

Tags: linux, networking, dns

The computer i am working on has a manual network configuration i need to keep. The DNS address has been written to file /etc/resolv.conf but the network manager rewrites a default configuration in it at every startup.

Notice i don't want to configure the network manager with this DNS address i would like to do it manually. is there a way i can stop the network manager permanently ? 
I already tried preventing it from rewriting on the file but that doesn't work.

Comment: ``chattr +i`` on the file will work for sure, in case you find the other NM features handy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming Debian based distribution (Mint, Ubuntu),

`apt-get remove network-manager`

should do it :)

you then need to add network configuration in /etc/network/interfaces (see `man interfaces`).

You may need to `apt-get install resolvconf` for `ifup` to be able to populate `/etc/resolv.conf`. You can add IP and DNS stanzas in interfaces file if the settings are static.

Note that session managers may list network-manager as required, and refuse to start without it. You will have to remove it from the list of mandatory session components. I have done it long ago, don't remember where they are listed - search engine is your friend :)

Comment: the solution sound promising, but to remove the network-manager, i have to remove cinnamon (linux mint) and i don't really want that to happen. I have checked the other options suggested by apt and none sound better.

Comment: cinamon is simply a metapackage and it is OK to remove it - this does not affect desktop environment. Just don't `apt-get autoremove` after you've done it - that **WILL** remove all desktop environment.
Alternatively, you can leave network-manager as is, and just configure the interface in /etc/network. NM will recognize the interface as "unmanaged" and will leave it alone. Leaving NM installed is rather pointless in this case, but if you are afraid to touch cinamon...choose your poison :)

Comment: @ArunasR "*Just don't `apt-get autoremove` after you've done it*" I'd like to be able to continue to use my system normally, including having apt clean up packages I don't need anymore. I.e., I'm having the same problem as OP.

Answer (score 1):

`sudo systemctl disable NetworkManager`

Alternatively, as [Jonas Schäfer mentioned](https://superuser.com/questions/818734/how-to-disable-network-manager-service-permanently#comment1072829_818734), `chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf` worked for me in the past to keep nm's fingers away from that file specifically while still letting it manage, for example, the WiFi card, but it's annoying to have to remember to `-i` it so that you can edit it when switching to another network.